# a simple command -- "np.save", maybe i misunderstood

Tags: python, scipy

just working through the example for numpy.save -- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Examples

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

outfile = TemporaryFile()

x = np.arange(10)

np.save(outfile, x)
```

***AFTER this command (highlighted), why i could not find the output file called "outfile" in the current directory? sorry this may sound stupid***

```
outfile.seek(0) # Only needed here to simulate closing & reopening file

np.load(outfile)

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using - `TemporaryFile` , which is a temporary file which is not stored as `outfile` in your directory.

If you want to save it to `outfile` , you can give that as the name and it will save it to that file.

```
np.save('outfile',x)
```

When saving like that to load, you will need to use , again the filename as string -

```
np.load('outfile')
```